# Retrieving most recent version of page with cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl

My site pulls in and posts a schedule from another site - retrieved using cURL.  The schedule changes on a daily basis, however, the most recent version of the schedule doesn't get posted to my site unless I delete the cookie file on my server, so I assume that the cookie needs updating, but it's not happening.

Extra info:  cookie file has permissions 644; I assume it can be read/written to as cURL creates the file if it's not there.

Thank you for any help!

Code:

```
<?php
$login_url = 'https://example.com';

//These are the post data username and password
$post_data = 'username=user&password=password&external_login=0&action=login';

//Create a curl object
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

//Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

$geturl='https://example.com/schedule';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $geturl);
curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $geturl);

$schedule = curl_exec($ch);

echo $schedule;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Here is the contents of the cookie file:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   code1234    codexxxxxxxxxx
example.com FALSE   /id/    FALSE   12345678    display_mobile_version_1620 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 
to the above and now the schedule is pulling the most up-to-date version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT TRUE` to force the use of a new connection.

`curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);`

I'm curious, though, as to what cookies are contained in your file.

Comment: This is really strange.  I took your suggestion and I know that the cookie file is being written on each call, but this morning I saw that the schedule is still showing yesterday's info.  Tried multiple browsers, cleared cache, no difference until I deleted the cookie file, then it updated with the correct schedule.

Comment: Very peculiar! What cookies are in the file? Do they specify a start date for the file you're grabbing?

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles upon this post, the answer was to set CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION true.  Thanks Set Sail for your help!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! +1 to your answer